# How to determine Google App Engine class type?

Tags: google-app-engine

Say I have 3 entities:

```
class A(db.Model):
  something = db.StringProperty()

class B(db.Model):
  somethingelse = db.StringProperty()

class C(db.Model):
  reference = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

where the Reference in C can be either A or B, how to I determine, given an instance of C, the reference's type (A or B)?

Regards,

Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this *without* fetching the *referenced* entity like this:

```
c_instance = C.get(...)

referenced_kind = C.reference.get_value_for_datastore(c_instance).kind()
```

or, if you already have an entity:

```
entity.key().kind()
```

See the docs on [Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) and [Property](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks a million, Model.kind() Returns the kind of the model, usually the name of the Model subclass.